# Run pool of jobs in parallel, each job only executing once

Tags: rundeck

I have a (powershell, if it matters) script I want to run once for each state.  The job takes a variable amount of time per state (and not based on state population or anything like that, not predictable), so what I'd like to do is create a flow with the 50 jobs as steps, and then tell Rundeck to run those 50 jobs in 5 threads.  Maybe 10 per thread, but probably not as some of them are faster than others; but let Rundeck manage that, so if it ends up being 8-9-12-10-11 that particular time, great.  I understand how to use the Rundeck API to create those 50 steps and add them to a workflow.

I can't seem to see how Rundeck would manage this exactly how I want, however.  The strategies for workflows seem to all assume you want to run all of the jobs on all of the nodes (meaning, if I have 50 steps and 5 nodes, it would run 250 total things, each state 5 times) - I don't want that; I want each job to run only on one node, but I don't care which node that is - whatever node is free.  Just act as a load balancer, basically.

Does Rundeck support this, or would I have to build my own load balancing script?

Answer (score 1):

I did an example using three nodes, three jobs, and a parent job to dispatch these three jobs to each node (once) via [Job Reference Step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step).

First, the Parent job which calls the child jobs using a parallel strategy which means any step (each job reference) runs at the same time, orchestrator as "random subset" of a set of nodes (three on my example) and "count" set as "1" (each job reference step to a single node).

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>3</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>17aad193-1e2c-45dc-b736-901c1de00954</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ParentJobRemoteParallel</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>node.*</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <orchestrator>
      <configuration>
        <count>3</count>
      </configuration>
      <type>subset</type>
    </orchestrator>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='parallel'>
      <command>
        <jobref name='HelloWorldONE' nodeStep='true'>
          <uuid>e1ec6d2c-62d9-4de4-af6d-7e03f59cc4e5</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
      <command>
        <jobref name='HelloWorldTWO' nodeStep='true'>
          <uuid>a57e74f2-050d-4a13-841a-3a4552d8227b</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
      <command>
        <jobref name='HelloWorldTHREE' nodeStep='true'>
          <uuid>47067c03-da25-43e1-83cc-9fe0492f0797</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>17aad193-1e2c-45dc-b736-901c1de00954</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Now the Child Jobs, these jobs are configured pointed to a set of nodes with random subset orchestrator and "1", similar to Parent Job.

HelloWorldONE:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>true</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>e1ec6d2c-62d9-4de4-af6d-7e03f59cc4e5</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorldONE</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>node.*</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <orchestrator>
      <configuration>
        <count>1</count>
      </configuration>
      <type>subset</type>
    </orchestrator>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "i am the first job"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>e1ec6d2c-62d9-4de4-af6d-7e03f59cc4e5</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

HelloWorldTWO:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>a57e74f2-050d-4a13-841a-3a4552d8227b</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorldTWO</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>node.*</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <orchestrator>
      <configuration>
        <count>1</count>
      </configuration>
      <type>subset</type>
    </orchestrator>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='sequential'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "i am the second job"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>a57e74f2-050d-4a13-841a-3a4552d8227b</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

HelloWorldTHREE:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <dispatch>
      <excludePrecedence>true</excludePrecedence>
      <keepgoing>false</keepgoing>
      <rankOrder>ascending</rankOrder>
      <successOnEmptyNodeFilter>false</successOnEmptyNodeFilter>
      <threadcount>1</threadcount>
    </dispatch>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>47067c03-da25-43e1-83cc-9fe0492f0797</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>HelloWorldTHREE</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <nodefilters>
      <filter>node.*</filter>
    </nodefilters>
    <nodesSelectedByDefault>true</nodesSelectedByDefault>
    <orchestrator>
      <configuration>
        <count>1</count>
      </configuration>
      <type>subset</type>
    </orchestrator>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "i am the third job"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>47067c03-da25-43e1-83cc-9fe0492f0797</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5DMd.jpg) you can see the result.

This is also appliable to steps, job reference steps are steps like a command step or script-step.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work when doing more than NODE#.   We want to run 50 jobs with 5 threads, basically - this kicks all of the jobs off at once, as far as I can tell (we made the test job be something with a sleep timer, and all of the jobs kick off within a single second even with a sleep of 5 or 10 seconds).

Comment: But we also only have one node set up - I was not expecting it to parallelize with only one node.  Is that going to cause this to work differently than it would if we had 3 nodes set up?

Comment: (And, to be clear, we took the above but made 5 copies of each HelloWorld job, so kicked off ParentJob with 15 subjobs, but left the counts at 3.)

Comment: From https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1047 I get the idea this isn't actually possible in Rundeck, sadly...

Comment: Another way to do that is to separate your jobs on differents parents' jobs with a static set of nodes defined to run parallelly. Maybe isn't the most elegant but should be work, or make some script based on RD-CLI (https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/) inside to some job that launches your jobs verifying the nodes (more complex).